# Custom Wpf ListBox Control

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollbar

I'm new to wpf and have just been given a project to create a set of custom controls which will be used to make a previous windows forms application more manageable and current. However I cannot seem to find much info with regards to customising the built in Listbox, this would involve preferably replacing the scroll bar and the +/- buttons with custom images etc..

Just wondered if anyone knows how to get at these ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for the default control template of the listbox.You can customize the scrollviewer there to do what you are looking for.Check the below article to get started

[Using Templates to Customize WPF Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Learn about WPF [styling and templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx). Other than that, the question is too generic for SO. Read the article (and perhaps google some more articles on the topic), try to style the listbox and come back with specific issues. WPF is not easy to get into, but it is definitely worth the time.